# Multithreading a 'raw' PowerShell server

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, powershell

I'm trying to create a multithreaded server in PowerShell, reason being that I'd like for the server to accept connections from different clients simultaneously.

I assumed the code below was going to work, but other than the fact it's not multithreaded as I wanted, it also has other peculiarities. For one, it appears that it doesn't matter if I call the `Start()` method on the thread or not, it'll run the code in `$ClientHandlerCode` either way.

```
#Functions
function send ($writer, $message) {
    $writer.WriteLine($message)
    $writer.Flush()
}

function initialize($writer) {
    $message = "Work in progress!"
    send $writer $message
}

function Parse ($input, $writer){
    send $writer "Don't be so impatient, will you?"
}

$ClientHandlerCode = {
    (param [object]$client)
    function ClientHandler([object]$client)
    {
        $stream = $client.GetStream()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $stream
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream
        $clienthost = ($client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).ToString().Split(":")[0]
        Write-Host "Client $clienthost connected." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        initialize $writer
        do {
                try{ Parse $reader.ReadLine() $writer } catch {  }
           } while ($client.Connected)
        Write-Host "Client $clienthost disconnected." -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        $reader.Dispose()
        $stream.Dispose()
        $client.Dispose()
    }
    ClientHandler $client
}

#Main execution
$server = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([System.Net.IPAddress]::any, 2648)
$listener = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $server
$listener.Start()
Write-Host "Powershell Bulletin Board System started. Listening...`r`n"
do {
        $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        try {
            $ClientHandler = New-Object System.Threading.Thread((&$ClientHandlerCode $client));
            $ClientHandler.Start() #It doesn't matter if I call this or not.
            } 
        catch {}
    } while (1)
$listener.Stop()
```

So to me this boils down to two questions: Why does the thread start on its own, and why isn't every client connecting to my server getting its own thread?

EDIT: welp, broke it. Thread won't start at all now.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+runspace . you might wanna have a look at tools like https://github.com/powercode/PSParallel

Comment: Threads won't work in PowerShell like that because there is no PowerShell engine available in a new thread to support it. You will be better off using runspaces to accomplish what you are looking to do. I did a chat server in PowerShell and the code in that might help you out: https://github.com/proxb/PoshChat/blob/master/Start-PoshChatServer.ps1

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll be looking into this.